# Adjust iframe height, Cross-domain, w/o access to embedding site

Tags: html, iframe, height, cross-domain

I am writing a website where people can easily gather feedback and place it on their website with iFrames. These feedback can be from 1 to 80 characters. With a font-size of 12px and a div width of 200px, the feedback can be anywhere between 1 and 10 lines. That is why the height of the iFrame needs to be adjusted automaticly.

Current code:

```
<iframe width="215" height="150" src="//www.DOMAIN.com/widget/5a.php?id=UNIQUETOKEN" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Note:**
I do not have access to the files of the site where the iFrame is placed, nor do I want to ask my users to add more than just one piece of code

Solutions that do not quite work:

- **postMessage**: requires more than just one piece of code to be added
- **Have a larger iFrame**: this would leave a blank space if the feedback is short
- **Have the user adjust the iFrame height**: I want it to be super user-friendly, even for people with zero knowledge of coding
- **Have a static feedback shown**: I can also have the user pick a feedback he/she received, in order to have a static height. Not my ideal solution, and the height would still be different per feedback, since some letters are wider than others (i.e. "www" vs "iii")

I hope someone can help me out here!